# captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection returns nil error

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

My custom camera is not working all the time. Some times it takes a picture and other times it silently crashes. My app is composed of 3 tabs with a tab bar controller. When I access the camera from the home tab, I can take a picture fine. When I access the camera from the profile tab, it wont take a picture and it crashes random places in the didPressTakePhoto function. I am not passing data in between tabs so it shouldn't be happening.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //Set current bottom border to photo
    borderPhoto.backgroundColor = newColor.CGColor
    borderPhoto.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0 + libraryView.frame.size.height, width: libraryView.frame.size.width, height: 4)
    photoView.layer.addSublayer(borderPhoto)

    //self.tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden = true

    chosenMode = "Photo"
    libraryView.removeFromSuperview()
    photoButton.setBackgroundImage(buttonImage, forState: .Normal)

    if self.isRunning == false{
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

        let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

        var error: NSError?

        do {
            input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
            input = nil
        }

        if error == nil && captureSession!.canAddInput(input) {
            captureSession!.addInput(input)

            stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
            stillImageOutput!.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
            if captureSession!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
                captureSession!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                previewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
                previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)

                captureSession!.startRunning()
                self.isRunning = true



            }
        }

    }
    print("Done ViewWillApear")

}

@IBAction func didPressTakePhoto(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Beginning Method")

    self.previewLayer?.connection.enabled = false
    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in
            //print(error)
            if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)
                var image = UIImage()

                if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .Portrait{
                    image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)
                }else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .LandscapeLeft{
                    image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Up)
                }else if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .LandscapeRight{
                    image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Down)
                }

                //Crop the image to a square
                let imageSize: CGSize = image.size
                let width: CGFloat = imageSize.width
                let height: CGFloat = imageSize.height
                if width != height {
                    let newDimension: CGFloat = min(width, height)
                    let widthOffset: CGFloat = (width - newDimension) / 2
                    let heightOffset: CGFloat = (height - newDimension) / 2
                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(newDimension, newDimension), false, 0.0)
                    image.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(-widthOffset, -heightOffset), blendMode: .Copy, alpha: 1.0)
                    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                    let imageData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.25)!
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                    self.captImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                }

            }
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fromCustomCamera", sender: self)
        })

    }


}
```

Comment: i think something is deallocating your object..!!!

Comment: could you please elaborate

Comment: @ConnorB Replace this line 
stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in 

by this

stillImageOutput!.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in
Hope this will help you.

Comment: that did now work. the error in the completion handler is returning nil and then the app crashes a few lines later

Comment: Both the samplebuffer and the error itself might be nil. You can't just `print(error)` because it is implicitly unwrapped.

Comment: that makes sense. However my app is nested in a tab bar. If I access the camera tab from the home tab, I can take a picture just fine. When I access it from the profile tab, it wont take a photo. I am not passing info between the 3 tabs so this shouldn't be happening

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. I had to compress my images because they were way too big for memory. Thanks to those who helped.